# Homework problem on pulling a rotating cylinder wrapped with massless rope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

I am trying to solve the following homework problem on mechanics.

[image]

The solution I attempted is as follows.

**Equations of motion for cylinder:**

- $F=ma $  $\rightarrow$ $100N=20kg \times a$  $\rightarrow a=5$ m $s^{-1}$
- $\tau = I \alpha$ $\rightarrow$ $FR=\frac{1}{2}MR^2\alpha$ $\rightarrow$ $\alpha = 50 $ rad $s^{-2}$

Then using $s=r \theta$ I determined the cylinder rotated an angle of $\theta=\frac{1m}{20cm}=5$ rad.

The time taken to rotate through this angle will be given from $\theta = \frac{1}{2} \alpha t^2$ $\rightarrow$ $5 = \frac{1}{2} (50) t^{2} \rightarrow t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ s.

The final speed of the cylinder will then be $v=at=5 \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}= 2.24 $ m $s^{-1}$. The final angular speed will be $\omega=\alpha t = 50 \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} = 22.4$ rad $s^{-1}$.

But this is different from the answer given. Is there a conceptual mistake that I am making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conceptual problem in your calculation. For the cylinder to roll without slipping, $a$ and $\alpha$ must satisfy the relation

$$a=\alpha R$$

which doesn't happen in your case. The rotation is simply unable to catch up with the linear motion. To rectify the problem, you must introduce friction between the cylinder and the ground. In the presence of friction you will get a new set of equations

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}F-f=ma\\(F+f)R=I\alpha\end{matrix}\right.$$

Together with the no-slip condition $a=\alpha R$, you should be able to solve the system for the correct velocity.